# Unable to start server after windows reformat

Tags: node.js, angular, ng2-bootstrap

Reformatted my computer and reinstalled node/npm + pulled my project down from github again and npm start fails with the following output (note this code still compiles on my laptop:

```
WARNING in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/utils.js
216:21-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
20:23-30 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
96:20-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
119:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/compile/index.js
13:21-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xmlhttprequest' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jquery\lib'
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js 8:28-53
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'location' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jquery\lib'
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js 13:24-43
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'navigator' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jquery\lib'
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js 17:25-45
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jsdom\lib'
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js 6:11-24
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser'
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js 7:11-24
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib'
 @ ./~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 32:10-24
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js 4:18-42
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living'
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js 5:11-24
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/cssstyle/lib/CSSStyleDeclaration.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\cssstyle\lib'
 @ ./~/cssstyle/lib/CSSStyleDeclaration.js 7:9-22
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\request\lib'
 @ ./~/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22
 @ ./~/request/request.js
 @ ./~/request/index.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\forever-agent'
 @ ./~/forever-agent/index.js 6:10-24
 @ ./~/request/request.js
 @ ./~/request/index.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/forever-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\forever-agent'
 @ ./~/forever-agent/index.js 7:10-24
 @ ./~/request/request.js
 @ ./~/request/index.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
 @ ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js 3:10-24
 @ ./~/request/lib/tunnel.js
 @ ./~/request/request.js
 @ ./~/request/index.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts

ERROR in ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in 'C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\tunnel-agent'
 @ ./~/tunnel-agent/index.js 4:10-24
 @ ./~/request/lib/tunnel.js
 @ ./~/request/request.js
 @ ./~/request/index.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/resource-loader.js
 @ ./~/jsdom/lib/jsdom.js
 @ ./~/jquery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/vendor.browser.ts
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 545 kB [entry] [rendered]
        [0] ./~/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
            [] -> factory:44ms building:2861ms = 2905ms
        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 4.09 kB {0} [built]
             factory:69ms building:39ms = 108ms
        [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
            [] -> factory:51ms building:180ms = 231ms
        [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
            [] -> factory:51ms building:183ms = 234ms
webpack: Failed to compile.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:40:38
    A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:40:46
    Cannot find name 'keyof'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:40:52
    '=' expected.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:42:46
    A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:42:56
    Cannot find name 'keyof'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:42:62
    '=' expected.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:58:42
    Cannot find name 'Partial'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:99:22
    Cannot find name 'Partial'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\node_modules\@types\jasmine\index.d.ts:99:35
    Cannot find name 'Partial'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\src\app\core\core.module.ts:14:55
    Module '"C:/Users/xaeda/Documents/lite-version/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\src\app\shared\i18n\i18n.module.ts:7:9
    Module '"C:/Users/xaeda/Documents/lite-version/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\src\app\shared\layout\header\header.module.ts:22:9
    Module '"C:/Users/xaeda/Documents/lite-version/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.
[default] C:\Users\xaeda\Documents\lite-version\src\app\shared\layout\layout.module.ts:16:24
    Module '"C:/Users/xaeda/Documents/lite-version/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/index"' has no exported member 'DropdownModule'.
[default] Checking finished with 13 errors
```

My question would be why would it be able to compile on some computers but not others. output from -v matches on both computers:

λ npm -v
3.10.10

λ node -v
v6.10.1

not running NG on this project yet. I have tried uninstalling @angular2/core and ng2-bootrap both locally and global, I've reinstalled node and npm. Something has to be wrong with my node setup or it wouldn't build and start the server on my other computer.

Comment: Are u available in team viewer?

Comment: No I wouldn't be able to get on teamviewer, but if there is specific output you want I can provide logs or run something